# How to use esky on windows with python 3.4?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, py2exe, auto-update

I'm trying to package an auto updating python 3 application using esky, but cannot get it to work on windows.

I'm trying to get the simplest example from the tutorial to work.
https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky/tree/master/tutorial/stage1

My environment:

```
Z:\share_space\esky-master\tutorial\stage1>python --version
Python 3.4.3

Z:\share_space\esky-master\tutorial\stage1>pip freeze
...
cx-Freeze==4.3.4
esky==0.9.8
py2exe==0.9.2.2
...
```

When run using py2exe as the freezer, it fails to find the py2exe module for some reason (though freezing other apps with "python setup.py py2exe" works just fine).

```
Z:\share_space\esky-master\tutorial\stage1>python setup.py bdist_esky
running bdist_esky
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    "freezer_module":"py2exe",
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\esky\bdist_esky\__init__.py", line 291, in
 finalize_options
    raise RuntimeError(err)
RuntimeError: freezer module not found: 'py2exe'
```

With cx-Freeze building the package works well but running the executable fails.

```
Z:\share_space\esky-master\tutorial\stage1>dist\example-app-0.1.win32\example.ex
e
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
Fatal Python error: unable to locate initialization module

Current thread 0x00001254 (most recent call first):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order got get a working windows build you need the following:

- The latest esky version from github (not pypi).
- To circumvent an esky bug ensure the character case of dependencies listed with `pip freeze` are correct and reinstall if not.
- I can confirm using cx-Freeze works (py2exe not tested yet).

See [this github issue](https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky/issues/86) as to how the problem was resolved.

Comment: esky on pypy is now updated so it should work out of the box now :)